# REMOTE_ADDR returns 2 IPv4 instead of one

Tags: php, ipv6

I am storing IPs to a DB which used to work under char(15), recently I get more and more IPs that look like this:

> '172.29.93.25, 94.56.207.248'

The majority of entries look OK, though. This is less then 1% of all cases.

The command I am using:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

The above IP does not look like IPv6 to me, but rather like two IPv4s separated be comma. How is this possible?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused that you have a list of addresses in REMOTE_ADDR.  I looked at `symfony` source code to receive client IP, as I see it returns `REMOTE_ADDR` as a single address, only `FORWARDED` headers processed as a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first IPv4 address is probably the internal IP address of a load balancer. The second IPv4 address is likely the IP address of the client and was probably included by the load balancer in the [`X-Forwarded-For` http header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For).

### Update:

I see you've edited the question and replaced an example with a `10.x.x.x` IP address with a new example that has a `172.x.x.x` IP address. In this new case, the first IP could be a proxy server. In general, you can have a comma delimited list of IP addresses in this field that could be arbitrarily long and it represents all the proxies and load balancers that the request went through. The last IP address is the originating client's IP.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this was just a bad example. I exchanged the IP in favour to another real error IP. My guess is rather, that this is some kind of spammer which is forging his IP.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad example. The first address in your updated example could be a proxy server. In general, you can have a comma delimited list of IP addresses in this field that could be arbitrarily long and it represents all the proxies and load balancers that the request went through. The last IP address is the originating client's IP.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: I fixed it now by removing the other addresses:  $tmp = explode(',', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
 $ip = end($tmp);

Comment: 172.29.93.25 is also in a private address range (172.16.0.0/12).

Answer (score 1):

The first address is a `10.10` address, meaning it's a non-routing address. Either this is a load balancer or you have a virtual machine (i.e. Amazon AWS) that has a non-public address that is reaching the internet through some gateway.

Answer (score 1):

The first address is a private address, you can learn about the [address allocation for private internets here](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html).